# How to get a Nullable<T> (instead of the underlying value) through FieldInfo.GetValue()?

Tags: c#, reflection, nullable, system.reflection

In an application I have some code that has a FieldInfo for a Nullable<int> and I need to retrieve the nullable value (not the underlying value) like in the sample bellow:

```
class Test
{
    public int? value;
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var obj = new Test { value = 10 };
        var fld = typeof (Test).GetField("value");
        var v = fld.GetValue(obj);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(v.GetType().FullName);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(fld.FieldType.FullName);
     }
 }
```

My problem is that **v** is always assigned the underlying value (in this sample an **int**) instead the nullable (in this sample a Nullable<int>).

PS: The real application don't has the type of the nullable at compile time, so a cast is not possible.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This is what happens when you box a `Nullable<T>`. You can unbox the object to `int` or `int?`, but not without a cast.

Comment: @dtb I understand that when boxing nullables the runtime will actually box the underlying value. But the only boxing operation happens when I call fld.GetValue(obj). I'd expect that either FieldInfo had a generic version of this method (so I could avoid the boxing altogether) or that the runtime would handle this differently (in the same way it handles it differently for boxing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case `v` is of type `object`. If `value` is null then `v` will be null; if `value` is some integer then `v` will be that integer. If you want `v` to actually have the type `Nullable<int>` then you have to declare it as such: `var v = (int?) fld.GetValue(obj);`.

If you need to be able to reference `v.Value` and get the boxed value back, you'll probably have to record the fact that `fld` was nullable (`Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(fld.FieldType) != null`). Note that generics will not help you here because you do not know the `T` at compile time.

Here's a helper you can use:

```
struct NullableObject
{
    public object Value { get; private set; }

    public static object GetField(object Target, FieldInfo Field)
    {
        object value = Field.GetValue(Target);
        if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(Field.FieldType) != null)
            return new NullableObject { Value = value };
        return value;
    }
}

public static class NullableHelper
{
    public static object GetNullableValue(this FieldInfo field, object target)
    {
        return NullableObject.GetField(target, field);
    }
}
```

Then instead of calling `var v = fld.GetValue(obj);`, say `var v = fld.GetNullableValue(obj);`. If `fld` represents a Nullable type, you'll get an object with a `Value` property; if not, you'll just get the value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as I said, a cast is not possible since I don't known the exact type at compile time.

Comment: @Vagaus: The "box" contains either the value or null; it doesn't record the `Nullable<>` aspect. Why do you need to know what the original type was?

Comment: My app visits expression trees trying to resolve expressions such: **a.b.Value**. While visiting it records a.b value (using FieldInfo.GetValue(a)). At this point I'd expect to get back a Nullable<Something> since **b** is a nullable. Latter the code does the same thing using the result of FieldInfo.GetValue(a) as the input for PropertyInfo.GetValue() (but this time using the "Value" property). And at this point it fails since FieldInfo.GetValue(a) returned the underlying value instead of the nullable and the "Value" property is declared in the Nullable<> structure.

Comment: @Vagaus, I don't see the need to even try to access the Nullable<T>.Value property using the PropertyInfo.GetValue method. As you've demonstrated with the example code, the return value that you expect to get from the PropertyInfo.GetValue method is the same as what you have already received from the FieldInfo.GetValue method; since you have the value already, why not just proceed with using it and don't call PropertyInfo.GetValue at all?

Comment: @Vagaus: You'll probably need a helper class. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Dr. Wily's Apprentice Suppose I have: **a.b.some_nullable_field.Value**: the visiting code sees "a" and push it to a stack and moves on; now the code see **b** being referenced (at this point it gets a FieldInfo to **b**), pop from stack (i.e, **a**), calls FieldInfo.GetValue() and push it to stack; in the next step the visitor sees **some_nullable_field** being referenced (gets  a FieldInfo for it), pops from stack and so on. See? Anyway, thanks for commenting... while trying to understand your point I figured out how stupid I am :). continue...

Comment: @Dr. Wily's Apprentice ...

even though not having a way to fix this I have a really simple workaround: just remove the **.Value** from the original expression tree ;)

The original source of the problem (a LINQ query) with a Where filter like: d.RowStatus == **rowStatusFilter.Value**. Simple solution, change it to just not access the **Value** property (I can even remove it from the expression tree if the developer insists on accessing it :))

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to get all the properties of "Test" class in an array of PropertyInfo objects. Form a loop and call "GetGenericTypeDefinition" method of "PropertyType" property of each PropertyInfo and compare it with Nullable type. Also check if it a generic type. If both are true then call "GetGenericArguments" method of "PropertyType" property of that PropertyInfo. This returns array of "Type" objects. Take its first element. This will be your required type.

If you have multiple nullable types then you can get the name of the property by "PropertyInfo.Name" and compare accordingly.

The following is the code which you can try out and modify as per your convinience.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Nullable_Demo
{
    class Test
    {
        public int? value { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var obj = new Test { value = 10 };
            //var fld = typeof(Test).GetField("value");
            //var v = fld.GetValue(obj);

            Type typeobjs = obj.GetType();
            PropertyInfo[] piObjs = typeobjs.GetProperties();

            foreach (PropertyInfo piObj in piObjs)
            {
                Type typeDefinedInNullable;

                // Test for Nullable
                bool isNullable = piObj.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
                    piObj.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>);

                if (isNullable)
                {
                    // Returns the basic data type without reference to Nullable (for example, System.Int32)
                    typeDefinedInNullable = piObj.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```